# how to subtract a time from a time in mysql in Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql, database

how to subtract time from already store time in database

```
$v_id = mysqli_query($mysqli," SELECT V_ID FROM van WHERE (v_starttime -'$row4') BETWEEN -1030 AND 2040");
```

Comment: Is it a timestamp, is it a date, what is time?

Comment: it is time that is store in database with data type time 
like 08:30:00   v_starttime is also time and $row4 is also a time 
i want to subtract two time and then see if valve is between some valves as i set then select it !!!!
may u get my point  @Kampai

Answer (score 1):

you should use TO_DAYS  for number of days then subtract from date

```
 $v_id = mysqli_query($mysqli," SELECT V_ID FROM van WHERE (TO_DAYS(DATE(v_starttime)) -TO_DAYS(DATE('$row4'))) BETWEEN -1030 AND 2040");
```

where $row4 is also date.

- know about [TO_DAYS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days)  and [extract date from datetime](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)
- You can use [TO_SECONDS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-seconds) to do this and do division 60*60

  ```
   $v_id = mysqli_query($mysqli," SELECT V_ID FROM van WHERE ((TO_SECONDS(v_starttime) -TO_SECONDS('$row4'))/3600) BETWEEN -1030 AND 2040");
  ```

Comment: $row is a time save in mysql with data type time 
and i extracted in in other query in $row thats a time just for example 08:30:00  thats what it is 
IS to_data is good for it ? @vKr

Comment: v_starttime here is also an field of table

Comment: sorry use to_days which return number of days from 1 jan 0001

Answer (score 1):

i got a idea do it may be wrong way but give right result yup done it

```
$van_id = array();


 $i=0;

while(empty($rows[$i]) === false){




  $v_id = mysqli_query($mysqli," SELECT V_ID ,v_starttime FROM van WHERE r_id = '$rows[$i]'");




      $f=0;
    while($rowb = $v_id->fetch_assoc()) {

      $ty= (strtotime($rowb['v_starttime']) - strtotime($row4))/60;
```

// here it is or how i do it !!

```
      if($ty>-40 && $ty<40) {
           $van_id[$f]= $rowb['V_ID'];
           mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE `emp` SET `V_ID` = '$van_id[$f]' WHERE `username` = 'bla'");
          }
          $f++;
    }


  $i++;

}
```

i simply extract time from database convert it then subtract already extracted time also convert it  too then just divide whole with 60 to get mintues then store it $van_id array